# Cylinder rolling down an incline in a vacuum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, friction

Say you set up an experiment with an inclined plane, and a cylinder rolling down the plane. Let's also let the experiment happen in a vacuum, such that there is no air friction.

However, let there be friction between the surface of the incline and the cylinder.

My questions related to this are;

does the cylinder accelerate forever? or does the cylinder have a terminal velocity? Does the cylinder keep rolling forever, or is it the case that, at some point, it starts slipping?

Answer (score 0):

In an idealized, Newtonian world (infinite inclined plane in an infinite, uniform gravitational field, infinite strength and stiffness of cylinder material, etc.) it would accelerate forever.